# How to get the array index of model class to pass corresponding data in another api in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here I need to get the index of particular array in which the key value pair `item.defaultShipping == "true"` then I need to the get the index of particular array and to pass in model class so that in order to get corresponding data so that it should be passed in another Api but when I tried below method it showing an error that `Contexual type 'Any' cannot be used within dictionary literal` in `let parameters` below line can anyone help me how to resolve this issue ?

here is my code

```
        var i = 0
        for item in customerShippingAddressModel {
            if item.defaultShipping == "true" {

            }
            i += 1
        }
        let arr = customerShippingAddressModel[i]
        let parameters : [String: Any] = ["address":
            [ "region": "\(arr.region.region)",
                "region_code": "\(arr.region.regionCode)",
                "region_id": "\(arr.region.regionId)",
                "country_id": "\(arr.countryId)",
                "company": "\(arr.company)",
                "telephone": "\(arr.telephone)",
                "postcode": "\(arr.postCode)",
                "city": "\(arr.city)",
                "firstname": "\(arr.firstName)",
                "lastname": "\(arr.lastName)",
                "email": "\(arr.email)",
                "prefix": "",
                "sameAsBilling": 1,
                "street": ["0": "\((arr.customerStreet[0])!)",
                    "1": "\((arr.customerStreet[1])!)"]]]
        print(parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 3 you can use `enumerated()` which will allow you to have the index and the value as the following:

```
for (index, item) in customerShippingAddressModel.enumerated() {
  if item.defaultShipping == "true" {
    // you can get the item and index value here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Review your code. The code in the image does not make any sense.